# Inserção, edição, remoção e visualizacao de dados Assincronicamente

Tags: php, ajax, json, pdo, assincronismo

Possuo um CRUD em PHP desenvolvido com o padrão MVC, toda a interação com o banco de dados é realizado com PDO, meu desafio é, passar todas as requisições de dados de forma assíncronas utilizando Ajax e Json.
Possuo somente conhecimento teórico sobre requisições assíncronas e gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de efetuar essa alteração? existe algum framework que pode ser realizado?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar Jquary para ajudar nas suas solicitações assíncronas. Com um simples código como esse abaixo você consegue fazer uma solicitação assíncrona.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "demo_test.txt",
    method: "GET",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" },
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Olá Phelipe, minha principal duvida é como repassar essas informações seguindo o padrão MVC

Comment: Usando AJAX você já vai estar preservando a estrutura MVC. Tudo que vc mandar imprimir no seu código PHP vai estar na variável result. Logo, supondo que você queira imprimir uma tabela por exemplo, você pode montar um json no seu back-end, recuperar essas informações pela variável result no seu javascript, e a partir dai fazer oq vc quiser com ela. O Javascript oferece uma gama de ferramentas completa para manipular o DOM, portanto você consegue manipular sua página separando completamente front-end e back-end

Comment: Acho que entendi a ideia do processo, vou tentar implementar no código e, se necessário, retorno a pergunta. Muito obrigado pela ajuda Phelipe!